# Where can I find data about battery life of current Windows Phone 8 phones?

Tags: battery

Where can I find data about battery life of current Windows Phone 8 phone models?

Comment: Question falls into the category ["Which phone is better?"](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: @Aschratt - Thanks for caring but I don't agree. There must be specific answer to this question.

Comment: @Pol But how long will that answer be relevant?

Comment: As above, unfortunately this question isn't a good fit for the site. Answers are likely to only be relevant until a new phone is released.

Comment: @row1 - Technical questions are always subject to time but I edited question to make it more specific.

Comment: @Pol thanks for editing it. I am still not sure if it is the best question as you are not really asking about using Windows Phone, you a really asking for a website that lists phone battery capacities.

Comment: Answers are likely to only be relevant until a new phone is released

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry my answer isn't direct (as others said, this is a question for a hardware-reviewing site, of which there are many varying opinions), but here's my take:
The technology of the battery itself has not changed very much over the years. Largely, the time that the battery will last you is dependent on how many programs run in the background over time, as well as features like the size of the screen, strength of the backlight, etc. My own opinion is that no matter which phone you get (Androids too, of course) you actually have quite a lot of control over how much battery life your phone uses; the biggest factor is which apps you install (and allow to run in the background)